# 2D Array from text input with space inbetween

Tags: c++

Given text input of

```
Car 23 1
Pencil 54 12
Draw 
Ball 12
```

I would like to print into a 2D vector such as:

```
vector<vector<string>> final_vec = {{Car,23,1},{Pencil,54,12},{Draw},{Ball,12}}
```

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>

using std::cout; using std::endl;
using std::ifstream;
using std::vector;
using std::string;

void read_file(const string &fname) {
    ifstream in_file(fname);
    string token, line;
    vector<string> temp_vec;
    vector<vector<string>> final_vec;

    while ( getline(in_file, line) ) { //for each line in file
        while( in_file >> token ) { //for each element in line
            in_file >> token;
            temp_vec.push_back(token); 
        }
        final_vec.push_back(temp_vec);
        temp_vec.clear();
        }

    for(vector<string> vec:final_vec) {
        for(string ele:vec) {
            cout << ele << endl;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    read_file("text.txt"); //insert your file path here
}
```

But I am only able to store each individual string element into one vector. How could I take one whole line, split each element into a vector, and then take the whole vector to form a 2D vector?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I iterate over the words of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/how-do-i-iterate-over-the-words-of-a-string)

Comment: Should be `while ( in_file >> token1 >> token2 >> token3 )`.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Thank you for your input, but what if token2 or token3 are empty? Should they all go to in_file?

Comment: Then do `while ( getline(in_file, line) )` to get the line, put the line into a stringstream, do `while ( ss >> token )` to iterate over each token in the line.

Comment: @0x499602D2 This was helpful! I have tried to make an edit to my code, but somehow I am still not getting every element of each line?

Comment: @user4581301 I thought I had it at that time, but I still couldn't figure out how to work with the in_file and token. After doing research into it for an hour, I couldn't find any implementations. If you can, please show how I can use while ( ss >> token )?

Comment: Shoot. When the question vanished I thought you had it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the basic structure, you just need to create the stringstream and use that for the extraction:

```
while (getline(in_file, line)) {
  stringstream ss(line);
  vector<string> temp_vec;
  string str;
  while (ss >> str) {
    temp_vec.push_back(str);
  }
  final_vec.push_back(temp_vec);
}
```

Comment: Flawless! I wasn't sure how to integrate the stringstream into my loop, and now I learned how to make a 2D vector out of a text file. Thanks a ton!